# Keras output single value through argmax

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to build a really simple neural network in Keras:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(40, input_dim=186, activation='relu', name='x'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

This works, and outputs a three-dimensional vector (e.g. `0 1 0`). I'd like to add a layer that uses argmax to send out a single value, rather than this vector.

I figured this would work:

```
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.cast(K.argmax(x), dtype='float32')))
```

But this throws (5962 is the number of training samples):

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected lambda_1 to have 1 dimensions, but got array with shape (5962, 3)
```

How would I achieve this?

Note that I'd like this in the model as an actual ArgMax layer, similar to [TensorFlow's ArgMax](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/argmax).

Comment: You can't do that in training phase, since `.argmax` is not a differentiable operation. However, the error is telling you that the labels you have provided have a shape of `(num_samples, 3)`, but the output of `Lambda` layer is of shape `(num_samples, 1)`.

Comment: @today, that makes sense, but how can does TensorFlow do this then? E.g. [here](https://github.com/uTensor/utensor-mnist-demo/blob/master/tensorflow-models/deep_mlp.py#L48) it shows an `argmax` layer in the model defintion...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @today for pointing me in the right direction. You should add the layer *after* training and all is fine:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(40, input_dim=186, activation='relu', name='x'))
model.add(Dense(classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=50, epochs=100, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.cast(K.argmax(x), dtype='float32'), name='y_pred'))
model.save('data/trained.h5')
```

This will now have added the ArgMax layer to the model!

Answer (score 4):

Tensorflow provides a method to build custom layers which run custom functions called [Lambda layers](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/lambda/). This is what were used in the first answer.

However, another way is to use a [subclass layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer) `keras.layers.Layer`  which is more advanced and gives more flexbility.

Examples of subclass layers:

- Scaling layer:

Multipies by a scaling factor

```
 class ScaleLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
      super(ScaleLayer, self).__init__()
      self.scale = tf.Variable(1.)

    def call(self, inputs):
      return inputs * self.scale
```

- Argmax layer:

Retrives index of highest value.

```
class argmax_layer(Layer):
  def __init__(self):
    super(argmax_layer, self).__init__()

  def call(self, inputs):
    return tf.math.argmax(inputs, axis=1)
```

This is the full code a CNN architecture for a classification task on which I add
an `argmaxLayer`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer, Conv2D, BatchNormalization, MaxPooling2D,Flatten,Dropout,Dense
from tensorflow.keras  import optimizers
import numpy as np


class argmax_layer(Layer):
  def __init__(self):
    super(argmax_layer, self).__init__()

  def call(self, inputs):
    return tf.math.argmax(inputs, axis=1)


def cnn_model(image_x=100,image_y=100,num_classes=10):

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (5,5), input_shape=(image_x, image_y, 1), activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(10, 10), strides=(10, 10), padding='same'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.6))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
    sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-2)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


########################
# Model summary
model = cnn_model()
model.add(argmax_layer())
model.summary()

#################### TEST
input = np.random.random((5,100,100,1)) # 5 samples
print("Output:", model.predict(input))
```

Model summary:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 96, 96, 32)        832
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNo (None, 96, 96, 32)        128
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 10, 10, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 3200)              0
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1024)              3277824
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 1024)              4096
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 1024)              0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10)                10250
_________________________________________________________________
argmax_layer (argmax_layer)  (None,)                   0
=================================================================
Total params: 3,293,130
Trainable params: 3,291,018
Non-trainable params: 2,112
________________________________
```